# React Native Flex Box: alignSelf of child component does not respect Justify Content of Parent

Tags: react-native, flexbox

In react native sign in button I am trying to put icon as horizontally left  and vertically at the center and the text at the center both horizontally and vertically. With the below code as soon as I do alignSelf as 'center' on the Icon it looses its vertical position. As per the documentation alignSelf should only ovverride the property in cross-axis and not main axis. Here the icon is SVG icon.

```
    const GoogleSignInBtn = ({style, onPress, children}) => {
      const {buttonStyles, textStyle, iconStyle} = styles;
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyles}>
         <GoogleIcon style={iconStyle} />
         <Text style={textStyle}>{children}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
   };
```

```
    const styles = {
      textStyle: {
      color: '#007aff',
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '600',
      paddingTop: 10,
      paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonStyles: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 5,
      flex: 1,
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#007aff',
      marginLeft: 5,
      marginRight: 5,
    },
      iconStyle: {
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    },
  [Screen Shot of output][1]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      textStyle: {
      color: '#007aff',
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '600',
      paddingTop: 10,
      paddingBottom: 10,
      marginHorizontal: 'auto',
    },
    buttonStyles: {
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 5,
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#007aff',
      marginLeft: 5,
      marginRight: 5,
    },
      iconStyle: {
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      alignSelf: 'center',
    },
});
```

You are indeed overriding `alignItems`, however it seems for whatever reason your `flexDirection` is implicitly set to `'column'`, so the icon is being set to the top of the flexbox.

Changing `flexDirection` to `'row'` allows the items to be oriented horizontally, and thus `alignSelf` works as desired.

Additionally, I used `marginHoritonal: auto` to center the text.
See [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no “justify-items” and “justify-self” properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/10683986) for more information on this.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the text is stuck at left and not in the centre, with the parent container set as       justifyContent: 'flex-start',alignItems: 'center', the logo will be horizontally left and vertically centred already so applying align self which is now effective on vertical direction due to flexDirection: 'row', (cross axis) wont give any difference. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is correct, `alignSelf: 'center'` will have no effect in this case, i'm not sure what's wrong with your `children`, I don't know what the object is so I used some plain text instead. [Here's my snack you can test with](https://snack.expo.io/@whalesauce/bad-strawberries)

Comment: Hi thanks,Children is just a plain text passed as prop.children, is the code working for you? I am using vanilla react native, wondering if there is any side effects from other places